# How to Create Devex-like Dropdownmenu (ASP.net C#) to Replace ASPxComboBox?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu, devexpress, aspxcombobox

The latest version of DevEx doesn't support IE7 so some of my pages which uses an ASPXComboBox will not function correctly when visiting the site through IE7.

Bottomline, I need to replace my ASPXComboBox with either an html component or jquery whichever is better as long as it could function like my current comboboxes.

Can you give me an efficient way to do this?

Comment: I guess this link might be helpful to you : https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q235836

Comment: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18646

Comment: i don't think anything from devex would help since they already said that whatever issue IE 7 has with their controls, they wouldn't provide a fix because they don't support the browser anymore. Also, we are already using the ieCompatibilityVersion fix but the page still doesn't work when using an IE7. Thanks for ur suggestion though.